# how to set coreSize parameter in Hystrix?

Tags: hystrix

I'm working on a spring boot project about electronic contract recently.And There has an interface of raiseContract().Considering that the traffic of this interface will be large in the future,My Leader let me use Hystrix to defender it.And I did not use it before.I am learning it and trying to use it on the interface.I use ThreadPool Isolation Strategy and I don't konw how to set 
the parameter of coreSize reasonable in ThreadPoolProperties.In other words,I want to know what should I follow to set it.

I did a lot of research,but I did not get the answer.All of Answer is about the meaning of coreSize,maxQueueSize etc.

Here is my code:

```java
@HystrixCommand(
            groupKey = "contractGroup",
            commandKey = "raiseContract",
            fallbackMethod = "raiseContractFallback",
            threadPoolProperties = {
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "20"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "150"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "queueSizeRejectionThreshold", value = "100")},
            commandProperties = {
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "15000"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "5"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage", value = "50"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "3000"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests", value = "20")
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already aware of, there are 3 main threadPool configurations:

1. coreSize: Number of threads that will be maintained in the pool
2. maxSize: Defines how much extra threads are allowed in case need arises.
3. maxQueueSize: Queue size of the tasks

Now lets start with an example. Assume there is a service using hystrix, call it `HystrixService`, for which `coreSize = maxSize = n` and `maxQueueSize = -1` (default case). This means at a time **at most 'n' tasks will be executed**. Any extra task that is coming will be rejected (fallback will be executed).

So, in ideal scenario, you have to ensure that this `HystrixService` doesn't reject any request coming to it. You need to know at max how many requests can there be on `HystrixService`. So if throughput on `HystrixService is 10 Requests per second`, then max concurrent requests on `HystrixService` can be **10**. Now suppose latency of HystrixService is `2 sec`, then by the time it responds to first `10` requests, `10` more requests will come. i.e. `total requests = 2 * 10 = 20`. So `coreSize` in this case should be `20`.

This is same as mentioned in [hystrix documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#threadpool-properties),

**`coreSize = Peak Request per sec × P99 latency + some breathing room`**

Now, you can keep maxSize and queueSize a bit high, so that it doesn't reject requests, in case there are sudden throughput spikes on your service.